# Ion Refresher not updating page contents from API

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have this piece of code that is supposed to display previously sent notifications. An updated list of notifications is supposed to appear every time a user goes to the page, they also should be able to update the content on dorefresh (pulldown).

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ToastController, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { OneSignalData } from '../../providers/onesignal-data';
    import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-notifications',
      templateUrl: 'notifications.html',
    })
    export class NotificationsPage {

      notifications: any = [];

      constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public onesignalData: OneSignalData,
        public toastCtrl: ToastController,
      ) {}

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad NotificationsPage');
        this.updateNotifications();
      }

      updateNotifications(){
        this.onesignalData.getNotifications().subscribe((notifications) => {
          this.notifications = notifications;
          console.log(notifications)
        });    
      }

      doRefresh(refresher: Refresher) {
        this.onesignalData.getNotifications().subscribe((notifications) => {
          this.notifications = notifications;
          console.log(notifications)    
          setTimeout(() => {
            //this.updateNotifications();
            refresher.complete();

            const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'Push Notifications have been updated.',
              duration: 3000
            });
            toast.present();
          }, 1000);
        });  
      }  
    }
```

Which is supposed to grab data from another file that looks like this:

```
            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
            import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
            import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

            @Injectable()
            export class OneSignalData {
                data: any;

                constructor(
                    private http: HttpClient
                ) {}

                load(): any {
                    if (this.data) {
                        return Observable.of(this.data);
                    } else {
                        return this.http.get('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?app_id=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX&limit=50',
                        { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' }},
                            );
                    }
                }    

                getNotifications() {
                    return this.load().map((data: any) => {
                        return data.notifications;
                    });
                }

            }
```

As you see I am running the service (below) again in the refresher function, but however the new data is not updated… unless I completely refresh the web page in order to load the new

```
this.onesignalData.getNotifications().subscribe((notifications) => {
this.notifications = notifications;
```

Initially I thought it was an issue with Observable serving old data before requesting new data but when I removed Observable from the equation I still had the same problem. Can you see what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the refresher even called? If so, is the http-request called? Is `data` always `undefined` in service? You need to debug your code and pinpoint the issue :)

Comment: @alex It appears that the refresher is called and data is being returned, however the data returned is old data. It is not returning updated data.

Comment: Okay, so is the http-request fired?

Comment: According to the console log yes, but I'm not certain if it is making the call or referring to old data. I will include a copy of the console log shortly.

Comment: @Alex I updated my question to include the console.log

Comment: The picture you are showing isn't relly helpful. You need to debug your code. Check if the request is made from the network tab. If it's not, probably means that `data` has value. So check that as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167573/discussion-between-javapatriot-and-alex).

Comment: Before chat, try answer I just wrote. I suspect your condition is truthy. Also you need to change `ionViewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

I still wasn't able to figure out why the data was being stored in disk cache but I was able to get around it by creating a random string and attach it with GET request URL:

```
load(): any {
    let timeStamp = +new Date();
    return this.http.get('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?app_id=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX&limit=50?tsp=' + timeStamp,
    { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' }},
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1))** You can use put your refresher function in ngOnChanges(), so whenever your data is changed at that time **ngOnChanges** will be called.

**2))** You can do one thing that binds your HTML using ** two-way binding [(ngModel)]** so whenever your data is changed it automatically update in the view. Like ex --> whenever this.notification data is changed then it will reflect in your view.

I personally prefer the first method because it is more convincing and easy.

Ex of ngOnChanges() --> As per I used in my project

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
        if (changes.dataSourceId != null && changes.dataSourceId.currentValue != null) {
            if (changes.pageId != null && changes.pageId.currentValue != null) {
                this.GetDataSource();
            }
           }
```

Comment: Got an example of how I could use ngOnChanges?

Comment: Check updated answer. Whenever there is a change in datasource than every time i had to call GetDataSource(). So I put it into ngOnChanges.